# Using jq how to pass multiple values as arguments to a function?

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have a json file test.json with the content:

```
[
{
  "name": "Akshay",
  "id": "234"
},
{
  "name": "Amit",
  "id": "28"
}
]
```

I have a shell script with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
function display
{
  echo "name is $1 and id is $2"
}

cat test.json | jq '.[].name,.[].id' | while read line; do display $line; done
```

I want name and id of a single item to be passed together as arguments to the function display but the output is something like this :

```
name is "Akshay" and id is 
name is "Amit" and id is   
name is "234" and id is 
name is "28" and id is
```

What should be the correct way to implement the code?
PS: I specifically want to use jq so please base the answer in terms of jq

Comment: Is there a reason you're implementing `display` in bash and not in jq?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy display is only for the purpose of asking this question, the function which I want to implement is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major issues, and some additional items that may not matter for your current example use case but can be important when you're dealing with real-world data from untrusted sources:

- Your current code iterates over *all* `name`s before writing *any* `id`s.
- Your current code uses newline separators, but doesn't make any effort to read multiple lines into each `while` loop iteration.
- Your code uses newline separators, but newlines can be present inside strings; consequently, this is constraining the input domain.
- When you pipe into a `while` loop, that loop is run in a subshell; when the pipeline exits, the subshell does too, so any variables set by the loop are lost.
- Starting up a copy of `/bin/cat` and making `jq` read a pipe from its output is silly and inefficient compared to letting `jq` read from `test.json` directly.

We can fix all of those:

- To write `name`s and `id`s in pairs, you'd want something more like `jq '.[] | (.name, .id)'`
- To read both a name and an id for each element of the loop, you'd want `while IFS= read -r name && IFS= read -r id; do ...` to iterate over those pairs.
- To switch from newlines to NULs (the NUL being the only character that can't exist in a C string, or thus a bash string), you'd want to use the `-j` argument to `jq`, and then add explicit `"\u0000"` elements to the content being written. To *read* this NUL-delimited content on the bash side, you'd need to add the `-d ''` argument to each `read`.
- To move the `while read` loop out of the subshell, we can use [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), as described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- To let `jq` read directly from `test.json`, use either `<test.json` to have the shell connect the file directly to jq's stdin, or pass the filename on jq's command line.

Doing everything described above in a manner robust against input data containing JSON-encoded NULs would look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
display() {
  echo "name is $1 and id is $2"
}

cat >test.json <<'EOF'
[
  { "name": "Akshay", "id": "234" },
  { "name": "Amit", "id": "28" }
]
EOF

while IFS= read -r -d '' name && IFS= read -r -d '' id; do
  display "$name" "$id"
done < <(jq -j '
  def stripnuls: sub("\u0000"; "<NUL>");
  .[] | ((.name | stripnuls), "\u0000", (.id | stripnuls), "\u0000")
' <test.json)
```

You can see the above running at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/BelovedForestgreenUnits#main.sh

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation.

```
jq '.[] | "The name is \(.name) and id \(.id)"'
```

Result:

```
"The name is Akshay and id 234"
"The name is Amit and id 28"
"The name is hi and id 28"
```

If you want to get rid of the double-quotes from each object, then:

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | "The name is \(.name) and is \(.id)"'
```

https://jqplay.org/s/-lkpHROTBk0